# Updating field in geodatabase table depending on other field using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, file-geodatabase, performance, update

I have a table in a file geodatabase that has "FieldA" and "FieldB".

I want to update FieldB with one of two values, depending on if there are one or more records with the same value of FieldA.

Example:

```
FieldA   FieldB

   1        0

   2        1

   2        1

   3        0
```

I've tried this way

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(featureClass, ("FieldA", "FieldB")) as cursor:

for rupd in cursor:

    rows = [row for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(featureClass, 'FieldA=' + str(rupd[0]) )]

    if len(rows)>1:
        rupd[1]=0
    else:
        rupd[1]=1

    cursor.updateRow(rupd)
```

The table has around 100k records.
It takes around 1 second each record.

Can this performance be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is slow because you have nested cursors so for each row in the updatecursor you are creating a searchcursor and reading rows. You are also using the old searchcursor (not da.) which is slow.

Instead first count all occurences once using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). The result is is a dictionary with FieldA value as key and count as value, for example: `{1:1, 2:2, 3:1}`.

> ...an unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary
>   keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values.

```
import arcpy
from collections import Counter

fc = r'C:\data.gdb\featureclass'
field1 = 'FieldA'
field2 = 'FieldB'

#Store count for each FieldA value in a dictionary
cnt = Counter()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, field1) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cnt[row[0]]+=1

#For every row check count in dictionary and update FieldB
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,[field1, field2]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if cnt[row[0]]>1:
            row[1]=1
        else:
            row[1]=0
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Never used the counter.
Great tip.
Thank you so much.